# how can i bypass a back-tick on a embed message?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do this, .setdescription( ' ${message.author.tag} Please type:' '?agree' '  ') but since there's too many back-ticks it will just give me an error but i know theirs a way around this i just not sure how. image that these ( ' ) are back-ticks i just put them because if i do back-ticks it will make the text into code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore the ` instead of ending the string, then just add \ before them and it will put them into the embed instead of ending the string.

```
.setdescription(`${message.author.tag} Please type:\`?agree\``)
```

creates

[image]